# Django 1.10.5 Python 3.5.2 Jsignature

Tags: jsignature

The app Jsignature is just what I need. It looks great. Unfortunate for me, I can't get it to work. Is this app the right app for Django 1.10.5 and Python 3.5.2?

I used the example code, made no changes and still I only get the button and not the signature field.

What I would like to do is this:
With data from the site (filled in by the user) I create a pdf. Herefor I use Weasyprint and a template. This all works fine.
Now I want to add a signature from the same template into de pdf as well. How do I do that? Can somebody help me?

Comment: To Django, javascript is just a bunch of static files. If it doesn't work there's an error in your own html or javascript. Anyway, you'll need to show us some code and possibly an error message, otherwise we won't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This is a new project and I only see the safe button:

settings.py:

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'jsignature',
]

urls.py:
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^sign/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='my_template.html'))
]

views.py:
from jsignature.utils import draw_signature
from myapp.forms import SignatureForm

def my_view(request):
    form = SignatureForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        signature = form.cleaned_data.get('signature')
        if signature:
            # as an image
            signature_picture = draw_signature(signature)
            # or as a file
            signature_file_path = draw_signature(signature, as_file=True)

forms.py:
from django import forms
from jsignature.forms import JSignatureField


class SignatureForm(forms.Form):
    signature = JSignatureField()

my_template.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ form.media }}
    <form action="." method="POST">
        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
        {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[save button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAhkh.png)

Comment: I have found the problem. I needed to insert jquery in my base.html. <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> And now it works fine.

Comment: Hi, I am confronting the same issue. Can you post the entire code you used here if you have it available?